# data migration between two mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, data-migration

Okay so i have two mysql databases with exactly the same tables  . basically one is a development database and the other is staging . What i want is to :->

1. move data between the two database, initially complete data and after that only partial updates to development database should be moved to staging

2)and this need to be manual and not get automatically updated (its imp. !!) .

I want to know what are the possible ways of achieving this .

currently i wrote a script in nodejs which uses information_schema to give me the tables which are updated and then fetching all the updated records from the tables sending them as json objects and the inserting them in staging database but information_schema is not reliable it sometimes doesn't give the updated tables and i think that's not the only problem with this method .
migrating data with api's doesn't sound good , so i wanted to know of better approaches to this

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create a mysql user having same level of access to all the databases involved in the process (if the databases are on the same server).

Then you can utilise `mysqldump` tool to create dump file from the database you want to copy (with selective specifications regarding tables, if needed), and restore from the generated dump file into your other database.

```bash
# for individual table dump
mysqldump db_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

To make the dumping process less complex for repeated use case, you can create a bash script for your commands involved.

**Detailed procedure**

Consider that you have a database named `oldDB` from which you want to migrate a table named `users` to another `newDB`.

Then, by using the `mysqldump` command on your shell (bash or cmd)

```bash
mysqldump oldDB users > users.sql
```

This command will create a file named `users.sql` in your current directory containing SQL commands and records from the table. Also, if you have a username & password setup to access your `oldDB`, simply use

```bash
mysqldump -u <username> -p oldDB users > users.sql
```

This will prompt for the password (if) you've set.

Now to restore the user dump from `users.sql` into `newDB`, use the following

```bash
mysql -u <username> -p newDB < users.sql
```

You can omit the `-u <username> -p` part if you've not set a password for `newDB`, else it will prompt for the password before restoring from `users.sql`. Also, this command assumes that `users.sql` file is present in the same directory as this command is running, but you can also provide the full path to the file in the same command.

Now since all these commands are bash commands, you can create a bash script file for these to run anytime. Save these commands (or more of them for multiple table transfers, or use a for loop with table names as list) in a file named `migrate.sh`, then `chmod +x migrate.sh`, and run anytime as `./migrate.sh`.

Comment: hey , can you explain a little more on how partial migration can be achieved using mysql dump .

Comment: Updated answer with some details